# Determine if HttpPost is instance of https

Tags: java, httpclient

how to determine if the connection is instance of https?

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestParameter.getHostUrl());
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestParameter.getRequest()));
        httpPost.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, requestParameter.getContentType());
```

Because I remember in `HttpURLConnection` you can do something like:

```
   URL url;
   url = new URL(endpoint);

    HttpURLConnection con;
    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    // you can do something like:
    if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can do

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestParameter.getHostUrl());

httpost.getURI().getScheme();
```